# QGIS select features by number of snaps

Tags: qgis, select, vector-layer

I have a situation such as this:

- downloaded OS map vector lines, which represent the lowest possible scale of 1:1250.
- all of them have exactly the same attributes as they come straight from the AutoCAD file (import DXF option)
- no option for polygonizing them and distinguishing them in a relatively quick way.

[image]

I am wondering if is it an option to select the lines with a specified amount of connections (nodes/snaps) with adjacent lines.
As you can see, I need just roads. It looks like they don't have many connections with other lines. If I could combine it with the conditional-based selection by their length, then I think I could get what I am after.

Comment: could you skip the CAD and load the OS data directly in to QGIS, then you'd have attributes

Comment: Do you mean OS data from the main website?

Comment: from where ever you get your data from

Answer (score 1):

Use Select by expression with overlay_touches.

overlay_touches will create an array of all ids touching each feature, and array_length will count the array. You can also try overlay_intersects

All lines touching two other:

`array_length( overlay_touches( @layer, $id))=2`

[image]

Comment: Function is not known  - this is the error I got now: The expression is: array_length( overlay_touches( "Merged", $id))=2

Comment: Your expression is incorrect, compare it to mine

Comment: Even if I put your one its thee same. Looking at your screen I guess my version of QGIS is too old (3.12), maybe this is why.